# How do I load API data into input value property on page load from React State?

Tags: reactjs, input, setstate

I have attained some data from an API and stored it in a state.

```
const [latestNumber, setLatestNumber] = useState([])
```

This is what is contained in the state

```
{
 "KeyID": 4676,
 "ApplicationNo": 607
}
```

I would want to insert that data into a READ ONLY input field, so taking `latestNumber.KeyID` from my API and adding it as the value property like so: `<Form.Control value={latestNumber.KeyID}>`.

**The key here is that **I want the value to load upon the page load**, not onChange.**

[image: You can see that the input is still blank on page load]

Currently the input does not display the data on load of the page.
Here is what I have tried.

```
const [latestNumber, setLatestNumber] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{

    axios
        .all([fetchData1, fetchData2])
        .then(axios.spread((...responses)=>{
            console.log(responses)
            setLatestNumber(responses[1].data)
        })).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})

}, [setLatestNumber]);
```

The component

```
                            <Form.Group as={Col} className="mb-1" controlId="formBasicDetail">
                            <Form.Label>KeyID</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text" readOnly value={latestNumber.KeyID} onChange={(e)=>setLatestNumber({KeyID: e.target.value})} />
                        </Form.Group>
```

Comment: Try to use an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue. Firstly you cannot `setState` directly on the array, for some reason because `latestNumber` *only contains 1 object*, you will be unable to access the object subproperties.

The API I am concerned with is the `secondResponse`.

Do as such:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async()=>{
        const firstResponse = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/api/users/${props.match.params.employee_id}`);
        const secondResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:3002/api/latestnumber")
        
        setLeaves(firstResponse.data)
        setLatestNumber(secondResponse.data[0])
        console.log(secondResponse.data)

    }
fetchData()
}, []);
```

The important part is how you set the state:

```
setLatestNumber(secondResponse.data[0])
```

**DO NOT DO THIS, does not work:**

```
setLatestNumber(secondResponse.data)
//followed by setting this as the input value
latestNumber[0].KeyID
```

To then add it into your input, do as following:

```
<Form.Control type="text" readOnly value={latestNumber.KeyID} name="KeyID"  onChange={handleChange} />
```

handleChange is just a generic handler to update the overall state of the Form